# How can I use ggmap's revgeocode on two columns in data.frame?

Tags: arrays, r, dataframe, dplyr, ggmap

ggmap's revgeocode function takes an input location in longitude/latitude format i.e. c(longitude, latitude).  See below:

```
revgeocode(c(-122.39150, 37.77374), output = "more")
```

However, I have a data.frame with two columns one for latitude and one for longitude.

```
df <- data.frame(longitude = c(-122.39150, -73.95945, -77.06136), latitude = c(37.77374, 40.71997, 38.90731))
```

How can I use dplyr, not data.table, to make revgeocode work i.e. get the c(longitude, latitude) array from the two columns of my data.frame?

Comment: @SymbolixAU Edited the question by including the example data and function I am trying to use. Please advise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution using the [purrr](/questions/tagged/purrr) package.

```
library(purrr)
library(ggmap)

df2 <- map2_dfr(df$longitude, df$latitude, ~revgeocode(c(.x, .y), output = "more"))

df2
# address street_number            route
# 1  1145 4th St, San Francisco, CA 94158, USA          1145       4th Street
# 2       93 N 8th St, Brooklyn, NY 11249, USA            93 North 8th Street
# 3 1312 31st St NW, Washington, DC 20007, USA          1312       31st St NW
# neighborhood      locality administrative_area_level_2
# 1      South of Market San Francisco        San Francisco County
# 2         Williamsburg          <NA>                Kings County
# 3 Northwest Washington    Washington                        <NA>
#   administrative_area_level_1       country postal_code postal_code_suffix political
# 1                  California United States       94158               2231      <NA>
#   2                    New York United States       11249               2858  Brooklyn
# 3        District of Columbia United States       20007               3345      <NA>
```

Or you can use [dplyr](/questions/tagged/dplyr) with `rowwise` and `do`, which returns a tibble.

```
library(dplyr)

df3 <- df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(revgeocode(c(.$longitude[1], .$latitude[1]), output = "more")) %>%
  ungroup()
df3
# # A tibble: 3 x 11
#   address   street_number route  neighborhood locality administrative_~ administrative_~
# * <chr>     <chr>         <chr>  <chr>        <chr>    <chr>            <chr>           
# 1 1145 4th~ 1145          4th S~ South of Ma~ San Fra~ San Francisco C~ California      
# 2 93 N 8th~ 93            North~ Williamsburg NA       Kings County     New York        
# 3 1312 31s~ 1312          31st ~ Northwest W~ Washing~ NA               District of Col~
# # ... with 4 more variables: country <fct>, postal_code <chr>, postal_code_suffix <chr>,
# #   political <fct>
```